# OTA in Atmegarfr2 controllers

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, atmega, ota, zigbee

Is it possible to update the firmware of the Atmega rfr2 microcontroller through OTA via ZigBee or Bluetooth. I am a newbie to this topic and there is no mention of the ota in datasheet

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is doable but not very straightforward. Have a look at the following discussion:-

http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/lightweight-mesh-otau

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the link,but it has "LW mesh" ,I would like to concentrate on one server and one client, so is LW mesh necessary for a single system ?